# Dialogo genérico no thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

Boa noite amigos,

Alguém já tentou ou já fez um dialogo genérico no thymeleaf?

O que eu quero é:

Ao invés de ficar escrevendo código para confirmar a exclusão de um dado na tela que é algo simples, eu gostaria de fazer um genérico, onde teria apenas o botão de confirmar ou cancelar, e aí só incluir na minha página.

Comment: Acho que esse tutorial pode ajudar: http://nixmash.com/java/javascript-thymeleaf-and-spring-mvc/

Comment: Olhei man, mas acho que ainda não é isso

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar layout:decorator e layout:fragment pelo que entendi você quer que o conteúdo das telas seja alterado mas sem trocar o que está ao redor como exemplo os menus.

na sua tela "Principal.html" você deve colocar um layout:fragment como no exemplo:

```html
 
<div layout:fragment="conteudo">
  <p>Conteúdo principal</p>
</div>
```

Nesse local será injetado o conteúdo que você colocar nas demais paginas. Nas demais paginas você vai usar um decorator, nesse caso chamei de "Principal" e implementar o "Conteúdo" do layout:fragment, exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
 layout:decorator="Principal">
<head>
</head>
<div layout:fragment="conteudo">
Pagina 1
</div>
</html>
```

Você pode olhar a documentação completa em http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html